# how to apply check mark on table view in iphone using objective c?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

i m trying for apply for check mark in table view, but it is not working, if i checked again at that cell again then check mark apply. but not apply at  new selected cell.
any one there who help me....

thanks aamir.

i m using following code

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table Data Source Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section
{
    return [self.chaptersList count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{



static NSString *CheckMarkCellIdentifier = @"CheckMarkCellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CheckMarkCellIdentifier];

if ( cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CheckMarkCellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSUInteger oldRow = [lastIndexPath row];

cell.textLabel.text = [chaptersList objectAtIndex:row];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
cell.accessoryType = (row == oldRow && lastIndexPath != nil) ? 
UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

return cell;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table Delegate Methods
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    int row = [indexPath row];
    int oldRow = [lastIndexPath row];
    if (row != oldRow)
    {
        UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: lastIndexPath]; 
        oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        lastIndexPath = indexPath;  
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: i think my code is same above, i match it, but not working well.

Comment: You can't select the first line at the beginning when your code runs. Selecting other lines should be okay.

Comment: Where to declare and define lastIndexPath????

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you mean that the checkmark doesn't apply when you choose the first line at the first time? You can add an else sentence to the code, but it wastes some time when running the code.

```
if (newRow != oldRow)
{
    UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: lastIndexPath]; 
    oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    lastIndexPath = indexPath;  
}
else
{
    UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    lastIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

Comment: i add else part also but it can't apply. checkmark only appear if i came back from my webview and again check that (past) cell.

Comment: Try to run the source code of the book directly, you may find out what's wrong by yourself.

Comment: Little Change i have to change to do for proper working   lastIndexPath = [indexPath retain];

Answer (score 2):

There is a funny bug here

```
 if (row != oldRow)
```

because if oldRow was nil (or in another words... "0" ;-) and the user press the row = "0" the "if" sentence will think this row was checked.

I fixed like this:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    if (!self.lastIndexPath) {
        self.lastIndexPath = indexPath;
    }

    if ([self.lastIndexPath row] != [indexPath row])
    {
        UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
        newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.lastIndexPath]; 
        oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        self.lastIndexPath = indexPath;  
    }
    else {
        UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
        newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

By the way... dont forget to use "self"

Comment: You can use [lastIndexPath isEqual:indexPath] to compare